# Mongo insertMany confusion ... reports no entries from CLI

Tags: mongodb

I'm brand new to Mongo but I thought what I was doing would be straight forward enough ... I have a large array of objects/records represented in a JSON file and I want to use `multiInsert` to load all of these records into a collection. The function below is used to drop the collection first, then do the insertMany:

```js
const importRecords = (db, collection, objects) => {
  const dbCollection = db.collection(collection);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dbCollection.drop()
      .then(() => dbCollection.insertMany(objects))
      .then(resolve)
      .catch(reject);
  });
};
```

This is called here:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
let markers = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/Markers.json', {
  encoding: 'utf8',
}));

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log('Connected correctly to server.');

  importRecords(db, 'marker', markers).then(r => {
    console.log(`inserted ${r.insertedCount} markers`, Object.keys(r));
    db.close();
  });
});
```

The function does run to completion and it correctly reports that 279 records have been imported. However, this is where it goes wrong. If I go to the `mongo` CLI and type:

```js
 use test
 db.markers.find()
```

I get no response at all. Whereas for other collections it returns all the records in the collection. As a side note, I have Fortune.js serving an API from this Mongo DB and it recognises and exposes an endpoint for `/markers` but the GET operation shows 279 records of "junk" ... well it may not be junk but it certainly isn't the array of objects I tried to put into it. Keep in mind that Fortune.js will be attempting to represent the markers in the official JSON-API 1.0 spec. Here's an example of what I get:

> {
>         "meta": {
>           "count": 279
>         },
>         "links": {
>           "self": "/markers"
>         },
>         "data": [
>           {
>             "type": "markers",
>             "id": "567de88fe58da85d041b40d5",
>             "links": {
>               "self": "/markers/_bsontype,ObjectID,id,V%7D%C3%A8%C2%8F%C3%A5%C2%8D%C2%A8%5D%04%1B%40%C3%95,toHexString,function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20if(ObjectID.cacheHexString%20%26%26%20this.__id)%20return%20this.__id%3B%0A%0A%20%20var%20hexString%20%3D%20''%3B%0A%0A%20%20for%20(var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20this.id.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20hexString%20%2B%3D%20hexTable%5Bthis.id.charCodeAt(i)%5D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20if(ObjectID.cacheHexString)%20this.__id%20%3D%20hexString%3B%0A%20%20return%20hexString%3B%0A%7D,get_inc,function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20ObjectID.index%20%3D%20(ObjectID.index%20%2B%201)%20%25%200xFFFFFF%3B%0A%7D,getInc,function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20this.get_inc()%3B%0A%7D,generate,function%20(time)%20%7B%0A%20%20if%20('number'%20%21%3D%20typeof%20time)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20time%20%3D%20parseInt(Date.now()%2F1000%2C10)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20var%20time4Bytes%20%3D%20BinaryParser.encodeInt(time%2C%2032%2C%20true%2C%20true)%3B%0A%20%20%2F*%20for%20time-based%20ObjectID%20the%20bytes%20following%20the%20time%20will%20be%20zeroed%20*%2F%0A%20%20var%20machine3Bytes%20%3D%20BinaryParser.encodeInt(MACHINE_ID%2C%2024%2C%20false)%3B%0A%20%20var%20pid2Bytes%20%3D%20BinaryParser.fromShort((typeof%20process%20%3D%3D%3D%20'undefined'%20%3F%20Math.floor(Math.random()%20*%20100000)%20%3A%20process.pid)%20%25%200xFFFF)%3B%0A%20%20var%20index3Bytes%20%3D%20BinaryParser.encodeInt(this.get_inc()%2C%2024%2C%20false%2C%20true)%3B%0A%0A%20%20return%20time4Bytes%20%2B%20machine3Bytes%20%2B%20pid2Bytes%20%2B%20index3Bytes%3B%0A%7D,toString,function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20this.toHexString()%3B%0A%7D,inspect,function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20this.toHexString()%3B%0A%7D,toJSON,function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20this.toHexString()%3B%0A%7D,equals,function%20equals(otherID)%20%7B%0A%20%20var%20id%3B%0A%0A%20%20if(otherID%20%21%3D%20null%20%26%26%20(otherID%20instanceof%20ObjectID%20%7C%7C%20otherID.toHexString))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%20%3D%20otherID.id%3B%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20if(typeof%20otherID%20%3D%3D%20'string'%20%26%26%20ObjectID.isValid(otherID))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%20%3D%20ObjectID.createFromHexString(otherID).id%3B%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20return%20this.id%20%3D%3D%3D%20id%3B%0A%7D,getTimestamp,function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20var%20timestamp%20%3D%20new%20Date()%3B%0A%20%20timestamp.setTime(Math.floor(BinaryParser.decodeInt(this.id.substring(0%2C4)%2C%2032%2C%20true%2C%20true))%20*%201000)%3B%0A%20%20return%20timestamp%3B%0A%7D,generationTime,1451092111"
>             }
>           },

Comment: Are you sure you are inserting into the `test` database?

Comment: pretty sure. my connection string is `mongodb://localhost:27017/test` ... doesn't this put into the test db?

Comment: yes, that should be correct.

Comment: But I think the collection name is incorrect: `importRecords(db, 'marker', markers)` should probably be `importRecords(db, 'markers', markers)` (plural for the second param). Just run `db.marker.find()` in the CLI to check if this is the case.

Comment: I thought I'd checked that but worth having another look